# Finding a character and deleting everything before it on every line

Tags: vim, notepad++

I've got a 10000+ list of my karaoke files which I need trim.

I looked at VIM and my head hurt, I was told to try Notepad++ and I'm struggling with the search and replace function.

Here is a sample of my list

> ```
> D:\Karaoke\karaoke\Backstage\8017\Queen - 17 - Hammer To Fall.cdg
> D:\Karaoke\karaoke\Backstage\8317\Alabama - 15 - Tennessee River.cdg
> D:\Karaoke\karaoke\Backstage\8717\Bee Gee's - 10 - You Should Be Dancing.cdg
> D:\Karaoke\karaoke\Backstage\9117\Billy Joel - 01 - Piano Man.cdg
> D:\Karaoke\karaoke\Backstage\9917\Reba McEntire - 08 - Somebody Should Leave.cdg
> D:\Karaoke\karaoke\BrightSpark\BRSP03\Brsp003-18 - Locklin, Hank - Send Me The Pillow You Dream On.cdg
> D:\Karaoke\karaoke\CHART HITS MONTHLY\Chm0002\CHM0002-19 - Diffie, Joe - Quittin' Kind, The.zip
> D:\Karaoke\karaoke\CHARTBUSTERS\90198\CB90198-01 - Lewis, Huey & The News - Heart Of Rock 'N' Roll.zip
> D:\Karaoke\karaoke\SFMW905\SFMW905-07 - Adventures Of Stevie V - Dirty Cash.cdg
> D:\Karaoke\karaoke\UNSORTED 2\Karaoke I and J\JD Myers - When I Think About You.cdg
> D:\Karaoke\karaoke\UNSORTED 3\Pocket Songs\PS-1299 Bobby Darin\PS1299-16 - Darin, Bobby - Mack The Knife.cdg
> D:\Karaoke\karaoke\ZOOM TT TH\TOP TUNES\Elvis\Tu169-14 - Hound Dog - Presley, Elvis.cdg
> ```

I want to some how find the last '\' from each line and delete it.

So they will show like this

```
Queen - 17 - Hammer To Fall.cdg 
Alabama - 15 - Tennessee River.cdg 
Billy Joel - 01 - Piano Man.cdg 
JD Myers - When I Think About You.cdg 
...
```

Its easy to get the .cdg extension off. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pure Vim regex may look different depending on `magic` setting, but with `magic` on (the default) the command removing everything up to and including last slash will be

```
:%s/.*\\//
```

`%` is the range that covers the whole buffer, `s/<replace_this>/<by_this>/` is the substitute command, `.*\\` is any character followed by backslash (backslash should be escaped by another backslash). Because regular expressions are greedy by default, `.*\\` will match all characters up to last backslash, not up to the first one.

While Vim has its own regular expression syntax I always preferred to use Perl for regexes which always look the same. If your Vim is compiled with `+perl` you can do

```
:%perldo s/.*\\//g
```

Or just run `perl -npe 's/.*\\//g' original_file > result_file` from command-line.

Comment: Do you know any basic tutorials on how to do this... I installed VIM and struggled to get into it. Know a way around with Notepad++?

Comment: Tutorials on Vim or on regular expressions? For Vim there is vimtutor - just type `vimtutor` in command-line and go on. I can't recommend any tutorials for regular expressions - I learned them when I was reading "Learning Perl" by O'Reilly book.